# Apply a function on all elements in a Dataframe

Tags: r, function

I am sure the answer is simple, but I did a lot a searching the last days, but apparently not able to figure out the right thing to do.. The problem is: I have imported a dataset via RODBC that shows what how much profit each user is generating

```
userdata <- sqlQuery(channel, query) 
userdata    

  USER   P1  P2   P2   P3
1 322    459 354  349  699 
2 232    249 311  349  699 
3 433    390 393  349  699
```

Then I have made a 4 functions that have their own set of conditions, and they will simply return a number, customer lifetime value. I like to use the functions on each of the columns P1,P2,P2,P4. For example apply clvP1() for each element in column P1 and so on. End result begin that the values in 'userdata' are updated, so I can send this back to database.

So if anyone has a tip, please let me know.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply function `clvP1` on column `P1` of a data frame simply:

```
 userdata$P1 = clvP1(userdata[,'P1'])
```

Complete solution:

```
 new_userdata = with(userdata, data.frame(USER=USER, P1=clvP1(P1), P2=clvP2(P2),
                                          P3=clvP3(P3), P4=clvP4(P4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a worked example of how you could apply specific functions to specific columns:

Example data:

```
test <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6)
test

  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Define functions as `columnname+"fun"`

```
afun <- function(x) {exp(x)}
bfun <- function(x) {log(x)}
```

Apply `afun` to col `a` and `bfun` to col `b` and so on...

```
data.frame(
  mapply(
    function(x,y) do.call(y,list(x)),
    test, 
    paste(names(test),"fun",sep=""),
    SIMPLIFY=FALSE
        )
)
```

Result

```
#     exp(a)   log(b)    as defined by afun and bfun
          a        b
1  2.718282 1.386294
2  7.389056 1.609438
3 20.085537 1.791759
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! It helps for better understanding